# fold div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fold

I want to fold down the div onclick event and on another click want to fold up the div

my jquery is following

```
$(".fold_reply").click(function() {

    if ($('.reply').css('display', 'none')) {
        $(".reply").show("fold", {}, 500);
    }
    else {
        $(".reply").hide("fold", {}, 500);
    }

});​
```

and the div I want to fold is having display:none at the initial point

In My reply tag
< div class="reply" style="display:none; " > at the initial reply is not shown

so when I click then div is fold down but on other div it is not fold up
Please help me

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [jquery `.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [jquery UI `.toggle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/) method which does just that.

But the error in your logic is the `$('.reply').css('display', 'none')`. This sets the `display` to `none`. It does not check if it is `none`...

If you had to use that code you should change it to

```
if ( $('.reply').css('display') === 'none') )
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".fold_reply").click(function() {
    $(".reply").toggle(500)
}
```

Toggle will show or hide the element depending on its current state, eliminating your if block.

Check this fiddle out for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9rGz/3/

Answer (score 5):

yes @levib answer is short and correct one to use. Another alternative is that you can use slideUp() and slideDown() functions.

```
$(".fold_reply").click(function() {

    if ($('.reply').css('display', 'none')) {
        $(".reply").slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
        $(".reply").slideUp("fast");
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQueryUI version of `toggle()` since you seem to be using a jQuery UI effect

**.toggle( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )**

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/

```
$(".fold_reply").click(function() {
     $(".reply").toggle("fold",  500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fold_reply").click(function() { 
     var style=$('.reply').css('display');
    if (style=='none') {
        $(".reply").show(500);
    }
    else {
        $(".reply").hide(500);
    }

});​

<input type="button" class='fold_reply' value="button">

<div class='reply'>
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQvZT/)**